# php - mail with attachment

Tags: php

I have implemented a php mail function for sending mail with attachment, but i am getting mail with 0 kb attachment. The code i am using given below:

```
<?php
$fileatt = ""; // Path to the file
$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = ""; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

$email_from = ""; // Who the email is from
$email_subject = ""; // The Subject of the email
$email_txt = ""; // Message that the email has in it

$email_to = ""; // Who the email is too

$headers = "From: ".$email_from;

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$email_message . "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
//"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
//" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

if($ok) {
echo "<font face=verdana size=2>The file was successfully sent!</font>";
} else {
die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
}
?>
```

I can't figure out the issue with this code. Please anyone help me!!

Comment: can't see a problem; check your spam folder

Comment: Other than using a library like phpmailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), what about if you print the content of the variable $email_message before sending. Are you sure that you read the complete file? How look your headers?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm an idealistic fool, but PHP's mail() function is plagued with problems, and seemingly always has been.

I tend to recommend that all new projects use a mailer library, such as [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), (or similar) because  they tend to handle edge cases much better than rolling-your-own, and also they've been more extensively tested against odd things that might get mailed.

There's a massive resource of PHP libraries available, other than the ones included in PHP itself, and many frameworks also offer Mail classes.  It's getting to the point where using frameworks and libraries produces a more rock-solid application, than reinventing many wheels, and rolling one's own to do everything.