# sending an mail with attachment using php

Tags: php, email

i have got this code - mail with attachment.......... but i get an error

```
<?php
    $name = "Reviewbox";
    $email = "jmaster@gmail.com";
    $to = "$name <$email>";
    $from = "Reviewbox ";
    $subject = "Here is your attachment";
    $fileatt = "doc.pdf";
    $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
    $fileattname = "newname.pdf";
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .

    $message .= "\n\n";

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $message .= "–{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "The email was sent.";
    }else {echo "There was an error sending the mail.";}
    ?>
```

but when i run this code i get an error as  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in C:\wamp\www\working\mail1.php on line 3"..... how to solve this ........

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815827/php-mail-with-attachment

Comment: @etbal ya that is not my code.....i took from net.. how to solve this......

Comment: The answer is in @Radu's answer below. Please don't say you have written the code then say you copied it from the web...

Comment: get a editor with php syntax highlighting, dont use notepad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `“...”` instead of quotes `"..."`. Looks like code copied from a web page that transforms quotes into "fancy quotes" and pasted in a text file.

Replace all occurrences of `“` and `”` with `"`.

Comment: @Radu now it issue me this much error  .  "Warning: fopen(doc.pdf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No error in C:\wamp\www\working\mail1.php on line 19".. what to do...............

Comment: It cannot open the file `doc.pdf`, as the error states. Make sure you pass the full path to the file instead of just the file name.

Comment: How did you give the full path? What did you write?

Comment: @Radu i gave as $fileatt = "file:///C:/wamp/www/working/doc.pdf". is that write

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?php
    $name = "Reviewbox";
    $email = "jmaster@gmail.com";
    $to = "$name <$email>";
    $from = "Reviewbox ";
    $subject = "Here is your attachment";
    $fileatt = "doc.pdf";
    $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
    $fileattname = "newname.pdf";
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .

    $message .= "\n\n";

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $message .= "–{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "The email was sent.";
    }else {echo "There was an error sending the mail.";}
    ?>
```

Comment: Props for taking the time to do that.